# Time remapping addon and motion blur problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, add-on, blur

The time remapper addon doesn't work well with motion blur turned on and motion blur can't be animated (nor the value neither the on/off switch). So the problem is, I have to divide the animation rendering into pieces:

- first part of frames with Speed factor=1 and motion blur turned on,
- second part with Speed factor<>1 and motion blur turned off,
- third part with Speed factor=1 and motion blur turned on,
  ... and so on.

So it has to be done manualy, and theres one more problem: when you don't render from frame no. 1 and previously you've been using Speed factor <>1, Blender will overwrite the previously rendered frames. 
So is there a way to animate turning motion blur on/off?

Answer (score 4):

Motion blur is a complex subject that can often require reassembling frames using optical flow technology.

Once you have your edit in place and can precisely locate where you require retiming, you might be able to leverage a tool such as [slomoVideo](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/).

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23206/repurposing-vector-speed-render-layer-for-optical-flow