# Track a pixel between frames using speed (vector) outputs?

Tags: render-passes

With a sequence of frames, I am looking to compute how each pixel moves between two frames (i.e., optical flows). For example, I wish to generate a "pixel movement map" that tells me, for example, pixel '(100, 100)' in frame 1 moves to '(102, 105)' in frame 2.

As [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23206/repurposing-vector-speed-render-layer-for-optical-flow) suggests, I can

> enable the desired render layer (ie "vector") and then save the render
>   output as OpenEXR file. That format will save all the desired render
>   layers (in this case, motion information in 4 channels) in a single
>   file...

I now have the OpenEXR images of size '1080x720x3'. The values range from around '-200' to '100'. Given the relatively small motion between two frames in my case, I am sure these numbers are not in pixel unit (also, they are not even integers!).

What exactly are these numbers? How should I process these values to get movement (in both 'x' and 'y' directions; pixel unit) for each pixel?

P.S. -- As I write this question, I realize there will be pixels present in frame 1 but not in frame 2. Not sure how this speed output reflects that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to my own problem after some research. We need to save all four channels, because

> R: pixel displacement in X from current frame to previous frame
>
> G: pixel displacement in Y from current frame to previous frame
>
> B: pixel displacement in X from current frame to next frame
>
> A: pixel displacement in Y from current frame to next frame

as discussed [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?133266-RGB-Speed-Vector-Pass-in-external-compositing-apps).

Updates after hours of debugging (sigh...) -- The above statements are NOT 100% accurate. The first two are accurate, whereas the bottom two should instead be

> B: pixel displacement in X from **next frame to current frame**
>
> A: pixel displacement in Y from **next frame to current frame**

Caveat -- the y-axis seems to be pointing upwards. I need to flip its sign to display correctly on my image.

I used [this MATLAB package](https://github.com/skycaptain/openexr-matlab) to read all four channels of the OpenEXR images.